# Convert the following to reported speech

Tags: tense, reported-speech

For this question, does the part "apologize..glass" need to remain in present tense or do we switch it to past tense?

> Complete the sentence by correctly reporting Sam’s advice to Marilyn:
> If I were you, I would go now and apologize to Mrs. Emma and offer to pay for the shattered glass.
> Start with: Sam said that if he were in Marilyn’s position ______________________________

Comment: Welcome! There's no reason to change to past tense, but you could get a more valuable answer if you edit to tell *why* you thought about doing so. Voting to close as lacking details, until edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam said that if he were in Marilyn’s position, he would go then and apologize to Mrs. Emma and offer to pay for the shattered glass.

In the reported speech, the part "*apologize to Mrs. Emma and offer to pay for the shattered glass*" should remain in the present tense as it reflects the advice given by Sam.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert *go now and apologize to Mrs. Emma and offer to pay for the shattered glass* to past tense, because is it not in the present (or any other) tense.

It is entirely governed by "would", and is in the base form ("infinitive", if you prefer).